# Create multiple records in rails with collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a messaging system where the user can select multiple recipients, and I would like to system to create a message for each of them. So far I got the controller like:

```
 def create

    @listmail = params[:recipient_ids]
    @listmail.each do |v|
      @message = current_user.messages.build(:title, :description, :user_id, recipient_id: v, :recipient_email, :tag_id, :industry, :strategy, :position, :aum)
      @message.save!
    end
    if @message.save
      redirect_to messages_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

The view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @message do |f| %>


  <%= f.collection_select(:recipient_id, User.all, :id, :full_name, {}, class: "selectpicker", title: "Choose recipent", multiple: true, data: { style: "form-control", size: "20", width: "100%" }) %>
  <%= f.input :title, label: "Message Title" %>
  <%= f.cktext_area :description, label: "Message Body" , :input_html => {:rows => 15} %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-custom' %>
<% end %>
```

But I get the error:

```
/Users/apulvard/Desktop/villas/app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:40: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...ipient_id: v, :recipient_email, :tag_id, :industry, :strateg... ... ^ /Users/apulvard/Desktop/villas/app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:54: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

What am I not doing well please?

Comment: Seems like the error is somewhere in the controller code that is not posted. What do you have on the line 40?

Comment: Line 40 is :

`            @message = current_user.messages.build(:title, :description, :user_id, recipient_id: v, :recipient_email, :tag_id, :industry, :strategy, :position, :aum)

` i just removed some of the field that are not relevant...i think

Comment: Please update it in the question, dont remove it. The error is on that line.

Comment: I updated it, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /Users/apulvard/Desktop/villas/app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:40:
>   syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...ipient_id: v,
>   :recipient_email, :tag_id, :industry, :strateg... ...

You are passing an **invalid hash** to the `build` method. The [*hash*](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html) must be a combination of **key-value pairs**. For example

**Not valid:**

```
h = {:email, :name, user: 1}
SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
h = {:email, :name, user: 1}
            ^
```

**Valid:**

```
h = {email:"", name: "", user: 1}
 => {:email=>"", :name=>"", :user=>1}
```

**Solution:**

You should change your hash to **key-value** pairs with the `params` that are coming to the `create` method. Usually this was the case before Rails 4. In Rails4, [*strong params*](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) were introduced. If you are using Rails 4+, you should define the **strong params** like so

```
def create
  @listmail = params[:recipient_ids]
  @listmail.each do |v|
    @message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
    @message.recipient_id = v
    @message.save!
  end
  if @message.save
    redirect_to messages_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:title, :description, :user_id, :recipient_id, :recipient_email, :tag_id, :industry, :strategy, :position, :aum)
end
```

Moreover,

```
@listmail = params[:recipient_ids]
```

should be

```
@listmail = params[:message][:recipient_id]
```

Comment: Hi Pavan, thank you for the very clear explanation on hashes. It works well now. Exactly what I was looking for.